# What is this "spatula" called, and what is it for?

Tags: equipment, utensils

I have this "spatula". The split in it perplexes me. It was inherited from a roommate who left it behind after moving out. It has a partner, that is a bigger spatula/flipper, with a hole in the middle. While the hole is large enough to be occasionally annoying, there doesn't seem to be anything abnormal about it. Based on the shape of the handle (and compared to the other (not pictured) spatula), the surface in the photo would be the "top".

[image: what is this]

Comment: Can you post a picture of both lying down?  (1 pic per utensil, please?)

Comment: It can be a simple  way to mold it as compared to classical slots. Also it could be used to take the margin of a tortilla/crepe for easy detacing?

Comment: I'll get a picture of the other tonight. Not convinced about it being a salad fork/spoon set. The other piece is definitely not designed to work as the other "half".

Answer (score 8):

Those could be a salad set,  similar to 
[this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Zodaca-Servers-Combine-Kitchen-Serving/dp/B01H37DBDK/ref=sr_1_7?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1514899142&sr=1-7&keywords=salad%20set). The two "spatulas" might be combinable to form a set of tongs.

Update: Salad sets generally contain a forky and a spoony component, which may or may not be combinable (and there are e.g. combinable pairs of spatulas). On the other hand, shapes vary widely, and there are two-spoon and two-fork sets, and maybe whoever designed this wanted to create a multipurpose tool (considering the straight lower edge).

Comment: I agree that it is from a salad set, but there is no hint of a hinge mechanism to convert into tongs.

Comment: Some salad sets just have to be used with both hands.

Comment: What I have is definitely not combinable, and the shapes don't line up at all.

Answer (score 4):

This is "multi purpose" spatula. Sometimes called "better spatula" but that may be brand name.
It's usually used for mixing, cleaning beaters (as in removing what is on the blades into the bowl), flipping and spreading.
I use it when I have to do many cooking task to do at once. You just wash it quickly with water and can use it again. Save time and place on the counter.

Answer (score 2):

It looks plastic to me but I had a similar tool that was made of wood and it was used to push the oven rack back into the oven!